# How to integrate username/password from Prefinery to my website?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, userfrosting

I have a website where I have integrated UserFrosting login management system. Now, I am using Prefinery to generate user credentials and these user must be able to login to my website without any registration needed. How can I integrate my username/password details from Prefinery into my website so that user can simply login to my website.

I am using MySQL DB. 
I did not find any code to insert user credentials to my MySQL DB.

Comment: So, you want to let people login to your UF-based website by authenticating with Prefinery?

Comment: yes, exactly. Thats my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So typically when you have an external authentication provider, you'll want to create a "register with Prefinery" page, and a "login with your Prefinery account" page.

I don't know how Prefinery works, but with OAuth-based authentication providers, they usually have a way for you to generate an access token that gets sent back to the application (UF), which then uses that to confirm the account-holder's identity in place of their username/password.

See, for example, how LinkedIn's OAuth process works: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

We have an OAuth plugin in the works (not done yet) that basically creates the routes necessary for the various authentication providers to authenticate the account: https://github.com/ssnukala/UserFrosting-OAuth.